# How do I enumerate all the BeanFactories in Spring?

Tags: spring

Is there a way to discover all the BeanFactories defined by Spring programmatically. I want to create a status debug page which prints out the names and class types of every bean in the spring application context, however I don't know how to obtain a list of all the ApplicationContexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below is a Spring listener which can be registered with the main spring.xml file for the web application, it builds a map of all the child application contexts and exposes this map as a property. The class below can be injected into any spring bean that needs it using @Autowired.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationContextEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent;

public class ContextsApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationContextEvent> {

    private Map<String,ApplicationContext> contextMap = new Hashtable<String,ApplicationContext>();

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationContextEvent event) {
        if( event instanceof ContextStartedEvent || event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent){
            this.getContextMap().put(event.getApplicationContext().getDisplayName(), event.getApplicationContext());
        }

    }

    public Map<String,ApplicationContext> getContextMap() {
        return contextMap;
    }   
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wire a [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) with your `ApplicationContext` that will allow you to traverse the `BeanDefinition`'s of a passed [`ConfigurableListableBeanFactory`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.html) which will represent all of the beans from your `ApplicationContext`.

With this instance of `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory`, you can find all beans of a type ([`getBeansOfType()`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType%28java.lang.Class%29)), or all beans with a given annotation ([`getBeansWithAnnotation()`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29)), among other things.

Comment: Do I have to register the BeanFactoryPostProcessor in all my application contexts. For example, the app has two contexts the main one spring.xml initialized with the the spring context listener and another one created with a Spring dispatcher servelt

Comment: You should only need to add it to one of them.

Comment: @ams I was wrong.  For `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`'s, you need to do one per application context.  Read here for some more information: http://www.dotkam.com/2008/07/09/spring-web-application-context-visibility/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ApplicationContext aware to do this.

```
      @Component
      public class PrintSpringBeansInContext implements ApplicationContextAware
    {

   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException 
     {

      this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
     }


         public void print()
     {
      String[] beanNames = this.applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
       StringBuilder printBuilder = new StringBuilder("Spring Beans In Context: ");;
    for(String beanName : beanNames)
    {
        printBuilder.append("\n");
        printBuilder.append(" Bean Name: ");
        printBuilder.append(beanName);
        printBuilder.append(" Bean Class: ");
           printBuilder.append(this.applicationContext.getBean(beanName).getClass());
    }
    System.out.println(printBuilder.toString());
}
```

}

You can test this

```
  @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:context.xml"})
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  public class PrintContextTest 
  {

   @Autowired
   private PrintSpringBeansInContext service;

   @Test
    public void printBeans()
    {
            Assert.assertNotNull(service);
          service.print();
    }
 }
```

Comment: But how do I get it to work for all the contexts, I know there are at least two in my system, the primary one and the one created by the spring mvc dispatcher servelt.